# Image recognition using Wand (Python)

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, image-comparison

I'm implementing a Python script to check the similarity between two images. I've been forced to use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), so I've chosen to use [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/index.html) as Python library. My work flow is something like this:

```
from wand.image import Image

img1 = Image(filename='/path/to/first/image')
img2 = Image(filename='/path/to/second/image')

# Normalize the two images in order to avoid exposition-related issues
img1.normalize()
img2.normalize()

# Create a 64 x 64 thumbnail for every image
img1.resize(64, 64)
img2.resize(64, 64)

# Compare the two images using root mean square metric
comparison = img1.compare(img1, metric='root_mean_square')[1]
```

Usually this method (root_mean_square) gives me a value of 0.0 for extremely similar images, >= 0.1 for images that are similar and >= 0.5 for images that aren't similar. My question is: is this a good way to compare two images using this tools? There is a better way? There is a better metric?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/25198558/2836621 and try Googling `Perceptual Hash`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check that out.