# How can i identify duplicate image that has a different size

Tags: c++, image, duplicates

The problem is that iv'e got a folder with more than 80k images and about 40% of them are duplicate. (some of the pictures are rotated, some have different size, but still its the same image).

At first I used hashing algorithm (with c++/java) to delete all the duplicate images(that have the same size and other properties).
But it seems it didnt delete all of them because some picture has a difrrent size (but are visually identical)

iv'e searched alot on the net to find any efficnt algoritam for this problem

the best code i found for my problem is with pHash, but its outdated and isn't working with VS anymore.

if someone have an idea for me, it will be awesome.

thanks

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204466/2836621

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the hashing algorithm, you could calculate the [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) for each image and then [compare them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching)

In rotated images histogram should be exactly the same, for resized images it should be very similar.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) there's an example of histogram comparison using OpenCV.

I still suggest to use hashing in first place because it should be way more fast and remove the first set of duplicates, then refines it using histogram comparison.